# How Inheriting loop work in node js for mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loops

all I try to filter question by comparing their id. for which I have created two collections. One all questions and second attempt questions id collection. In this code, I am trying to fetch first attempted questions id that stored in the second collection. And in the second function
I am fetched all question where I create a for loop to fetch all questions id. And I don't know this is right or not inside my first loop I have 
created another for loop in which looping my attempted questions id. So that it will iterate throughout the end point. But problem is it looping the first id properly and print in the console, but after this, it will out from the loop. Means it will not run until end of the question id

My requirement is that it will start the loop again from for(i<=1) after for(i<=0) from first start and next for(i<=2) till end for(i<=100). And also inside loop too in the same manner.

```
    try{
     async.waterfall([
      function(callback){
        var query = {'quiz.score':1};
        var select = 'quiz';

        childinfo.find(query,select,function(err,attemptquestion){
          if(err){
            return next(err);
          }else{
            callback(null,attemptquestion);
          }
        });
      },
      function(attquest){
        var query = {};
        var i,j;

        childquestion.find(query,function(err,questions){
          if(err){
            return next(err);
          }else{
            for(i=0;i<=questions.length;i++){
              var quest = JSON.stringify(questions[i]._id);
              console.log(quest);
              for(j=0;j<=attquest.length;j++){
                var attqus = JSON.stringify(attquest[j].quiz[j].questionId);
                console.log(attqus);
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }         
    ]);
  }catch(err){
    console.log("Error in your code");
    return next(err);
  }
```

2). This is my attempted collection schema

```
     quiz: {type: Array,
        questionId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                                    ref: 'Question',
                                    index: true
            },
            score: { type: Number },
            time: { type: String }
    }
```

3). And this is my second question collection

```
      title: { type: String, required: true },
        options: { type: Array, required: true },
        result: { type: Array, required: true },
        feedback: { type: String }
```

What I am doing: I sending a question to the front end and front end sent back questionId score in 0 and 1 format means if the question is right score 1 else 0 and it will store in attempted question collection.

Why I am doing this:Because I doing this when next time I am sent the question
to front end from question collection. It will be filtered from attempted
questionId. Means in attempted collection which question id stored with score 1 will be filtered from question collections and next time only that question will be sent to the front which question id not equal to score 1 attempted question id.

Comment: Hi Ritesh Kumar, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm sorry to say this, but your question is quite difficult to understand; could you [edit] it to explain more carefully what the data is in the two different collections and how they relate? For example if you show example documents from the two collections, that would help a lot. Also, I don't understand how you are trying to query across the two collections.

Comment: need to filter the question id from another collection question id. I had to edit the details. thanks for giving the reply

Comment: Could you describe what your problem is with the loops? It would be clear if you could show an example of the output, compared to an example of the output you are hoping to see?